# zend form how to check if a selection exists

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

If I have declared a multiselect in zendform class how would I check if it existed in controller

e.g. in zendform I have declared  select element "mySelectElement" with options [foo, bar]

how woul I check in the controller if option foo was declared as an option for my select element?

The options are actually dynamically generated in the form but the above example holds?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the options are dynamically generated in the form?

Comment: the options were generated from db.

I needed to be able to add users custom fields but only on populate.

In the end I continued generating the select in the form class from db, and in the controller I used the method in my answer to get the user selected and thus also custom fields to compare and added any missing, this was done in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$form->element->getAttribs(); 
returns an array key ['options'] contains the existing options and can then be compared via array_key_exists or in_array.